# Java Get One Day Before Specific Date

Tags: java, date

I have a String expired date. But I need to perform some SQL statement the day before expired date falls. I get my expired date and by:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String expiredDate = null;
String currentDate = dateFormat.format(new Date());
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

try {
            cal.setTime(dateFormat.parse(loanDate));
            cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 2);
            expiredDate = dateFormat.format(cal.getTimeInMillis());
            cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -2);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Then, I got an if statement to perform SQL statement:

```
if(expiredDate.equals(currentDate)){
                        promptExtensionDialog();
                    }
```

What I am trying to achieve is for the if statement, instead of the expiredDate itself, I need to get one day before the expired date and compare with the current date. I wonder how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

```
try {
                        cal.setTime(dateFormat.parse(expiredDate));
                        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
                        expiredDate = dateFormat.format(cal.getTimeInMillis());
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(LoanBook.this,
                            expiredDate, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
```

This returns me the next date instead of previous date. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using Java's (pre-8) built-in Date and Time API will eat you alive. Use [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) for complex DateTime manipulations.

Getting the previous day is as simple as this.

```
    DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();
    System.out.println(dateTime);
    System.out.println(dateTime.minusDays(1));
```

If you don't want any external libraries:

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String strDate = "2014-10-28";
    Date date = sdf.parse(strDate);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(date);
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
    Date yesterday = calendar.getTime();

    System.out.println(yesterday);
    System.out.println(date);
```

Comment: Is JodaTime an external libraries? If it's so, is there any pure Java ways to do this?

Comment: Joda-Time *is* [pure Java](http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/faq/faq0006.html). But not built in, you add a single .jar file. Don't be afraid to add jars. Easily adding libraries of classes is one of the main purposes of inventing Object-Oriented Programming (OOP) and late binding.

Comment: @Sergio But let's say my expired date was now a string. How should I implement it into your solution?

Comment: convert the `String` to a `Date`, then use `calendar.setTime(date)`

Comment: @Sergio Could you please help me take a look at the edited portion?

Comment: See my edit for the formatting part. If you have any other questions regarding this, I think it is best if you create a new question since this is already out of your topic :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works but actually I think I am not out of topic since I am asking the same thing in the first place :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)?  It is a fantastic library to do date manipulation easily.  In fact, a lot of Java 8 date handling are derived from JodaTime.

For your needs, you could do something like:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime(expiredDate);
DateTime dayBefore = dt.minusDays(1);
```

Comment: Is JodaTime an external libraries? If it's so, is there any pure Java ways without external libraries to do this?

Comment: Sure there are ways of using pure Java.  What version are you using?  Java 7 or 8?

Answer (score 0):

The other two answers are basically correct. But they omit the crucial issue of time zones and start of day. If you want all of yesterday, do something like the following.

```
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" );
DateTime now = DateTime.now( zone );
DateTime yesterdayStart = now.minusDays( 1 ).withTimeAtStartOfDay();
```

Convert to a [java.sql.Timestamp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html).

```
java.sql.Timestamp ts  = new java.sql.Timestamp( yesterdayStart.getMillis() );
```

Comment: So for your solution, I only need the first three lines in my codes and replace the zone with my expiredDate which is String?

Comment: (A) First parse any strings to get date-time objects, then do you work and execute your business logic. (B) As Sergio said, avoid using the java.util.Date and .Calendar classes. They are terrible. Use Joda-Time and/or java.time package built into Java 8. (C) All of your questions are duplicates, covered in hundreds of other questions and answers. Please search StackOverflow before posting.