# Datepick 1 day before Angularjs

Tags: java, jquery, angularjs

Im having trouble making the datepicker( angularjs-datepicker 720kb.datepicker), it keeps returning dates 1 day before of what it should.

```
<div class="col-md-5">
  <label>Fecha Disposicion</label>
  <datepicker date-format="yyyy-MM-dd" date-year-title="selected year">
      <input ng-model="vm.auto.fechaDisposicion" />
  </datepicker>
</div>
```

Im using UTC time for the rest of my app, and the back end is springboot data rest and the database mysql (datetime).

Here's the suggested [workaround](https://github.com/720kb/angular-datepicker/issues/125) in the git hub proyect, but I don't really get how to implement it.

Output before POST method: "2018-01-03"
Arrives at the DB like this: "2018-01-02 00:00:00"

MY java controller:

```
          package ar.gob.snr.expediente.domain;

      import java.io.Serializable;
      import java.sql.Date;

      import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
      import javax.persistence.Column;
      import javax.persistence.Entity;
      import javax.persistence.FetchType;
      import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
      import javax.persistence.Id;
      import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
      import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
      import javax.persistence.Table;
      import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RestResource;

      @Entity
      @Table(name = "auto")
      public class Auto implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -4601105083604023376L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY )
        @Column(name = "id")
        private Long id;
        @Column(name = "expediente_1")
        private String expediente1;
        @Column(name = "expediente_2")
        private String expediente2;
        @Column(name = "expediente_3")
        private String expediente3;
        @Column(name = "expediente_4")
        private String expediente4;
        @Column(name = "expediente_5")
        private String expediente5;
        @RestResource(exported = false)
        @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch= FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinColumn(name = "tipo_documento", referencedColumnName = "id")
        private TipoDocumento tipoDocumento;
        @Column(name = "numero_documento")
        private Integer numeroDocumento;
        @Column(name = "auto")
        private String auto;
        @Column(name = "patente")
        private String patente;
        @Column(name = "fecha_simbolo")
        private Date fechaSimbolo;
        @Column(name = "fecha_disposicion")
        private Date fechaDisposicion;
        @Column(name = "nro_disposicion")
        private Integer nroDisposicion;

        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public TipoDocumento getTipoDocumento() {
            return tipoDocumento;
        }

        public void setTipoDocumento(TipoDocumento tipoDocumento) {
            this.tipoDocumento = tipoDocumento;
        }

        public Integer getNumeroDocumento() {
            return numeroDocumento;
        }

        public void setNumeroDocumento(Integer numeroDocumento) {
            this.numeroDocumento = numeroDocumento;
        }

        public String getExpediente1() {
            return expediente1;
        }

        public void setExpediente1(String expediente1) {
            this.expediente1 = expediente1;
        }

        public String getExpediente2() {
            return expediente2;
        }

        public void setExpediente2(String expediente2) {
            this.expediente2 = expediente2;
        }

        public String getExpediente3() {
            return expediente3;
        }

        public void setExpediente3(String expediente3) {
            this.expediente3 = expediente3;
        }

        public String getExpediente4() {
            return expediente4;
        }

        public void setExpediente4(String expediente4) {
            this.expediente4 = expediente4;
        }

        public String getExpediente5() {
            return expediente5;
        }

        public void setExpediente5(String expediente5) {
            this.expediente5 = expediente5;
        }

        public String getAuto() {
            return auto;
        }

        public void setAuto(String auto) {
            this.auto = auto;
        }

        public String getPatente() {
            return patente;
        }

        public void setPatente(String patente) {
            this.patente = patente;
        }

        public Date getFechaSimbolo() {
            return fechaSimbolo;
        }

        public void setFechaSimbolo(Date fechaSimbolo) {
            this.fechaSimbolo = fechaSimbolo;
        }

        public Date getFechaDisposicion() {
            return fechaDisposicion;
        }

        public void setFechaDisposicion(Date fechaDisposicion) {
            this.fechaDisposicion = fechaDisposicion;
        }

        public Integer getNroDisposicion() {
            return nroDisposicion;
        }

        public void setNroDisposicion(Integer nroDisposicion) {
            this.nroDisposicion = nroDisposicion;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            Auto other = (Auto) obj;
            if (id == null) {
                if (other.id != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
                return false;
            return true;
        }

      }
```

Comment: Not able to replicate your error, provide gist of your code. Check this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/34Lz8pfg/

Comment: It might be a java problem coz the output seems to be fine before the "post" but arrives in the DB 1 day short. edited main post

Comment: JAVA, there is always date time problem with java.  Check this post our maybe it helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26599946/java-get-one-day-before-specific-date